# How to omit/ignore tags like <br> when passing PHP content to a YAML file?

Tags: php, printing, yaml, file-put-contents

I want to 'print' the output of a PHP file into a YAML

My original PHP output looks like this:

[image]

, and goes on for 150 more blocks.

As you can see, it has the YAML file structure. I would like to print that output into the YAML file so that those 150 blocks are written like this:

```
  -
        ref: trade-67
        id: 67
        name: Plumber
        category: $trade-category-1
    -
        ref: trade-68
        id: 68
        name: Electrician
        category: $trade-category-2  
    -
#and so on...
```

Now, when I execute my PHP code using the `file_put_contents($MyYamlFile, $PhpLoop)` function, I obtain the following code in my YAML file:

```
    <br>-<br>    &nbsp;&nbsp;ref: trade-Ref: trade-id
    <br>    &nbsp;&nbsp;id: Trade-ID
    <br>    &nbsp;&nbsp;name: Trade Name

#150 times...
```

...as expected.

So, my question is: How can I omit tags like `<BR>` and `&nbsp`, and dump exactly what localhost ouputs in the previous image?

If not, is there any other better method you can recommend?

Comment: use php `strip_tags()` function to remove html entities from your string

Comment: Thanks, @RAUSHANKUMAR but it only ignores the BR part. The &nbsp still apears...

Comment: use str_replace() along with `strip_tags()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [str_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) along with [strip_tags()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)

something like:-

```
strip_tags(str_replace("&nbsp;","",$string),"<br/>");
```